# Subsetting reqAccountDeatils() cannot convert into Dataframe

Tags: r, ibrokers

When subsetting my Account Data form the return of
`reqAccountUpdates(tws)` to get my Account Details, I get a nice print on the console. But storing in a CSV yields the following error message:

> acct_saved <- saveDataToDirectory(accountNumber, tag_acct, acctData)
> Generated Filename: U7XXXXX9_11062023_acct.csv

> Fehler in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :
> kann Klasse ‘"eventAccountValue"’ nicht in data.frame umwandeln

This translates to: "Error ... could not convert class '`eventAccountValue`' in a data.frame, hence storing into CSV in a usual way does not work. Is there a workaround to achieve this?

The `twsPortfolioValue(tws)`can be stored in CSV easily

The Function

`reqAccountDetails()` returns a bunch of data. Applying `twsPortfolioValues()` returns my positions which I can store as a .csv.

```
acctInfo = reqAccountUpdates(tws)

#print(head(acctInfo))

twsPortfolioValue(acctInfo)
```

When subsetting like

```
acctData <- acctInfo[[1]]
```

The console prints a nice table, also `typeof(acctData)` reveals it is a list.

```
> acctData
                             value      currency
AccountCode                  U7XXXXX9           
AccountOrGroup               U7XXXXX9   USD     
AccountReady                 true               
AccountType                  INDIVIDUAL         
AccruedCash                  x          USD     
AccruedDividend              x.         EUR     
AvailableFunds               x.xx.      EUR     
AvailableFunds.S             x.xx.      EUR     
Billable                     x.xx       EUR     
BuyingPower                  x.xx       EUR     
CashBalance                  x.xx.      USD 
...
```

The conversion to a data frame is an issue

Is there any workaround to get this job done for my account details?

Comment: What does`dput(acctData)` show before you subset it?  Where in your data is an object of class `eventAccountValue` found?  What does it look like?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I found a solution. Subsetting like this

```
acctData <- acctInfo[[1]][]
```

instead of

```
acctData <- acctInfo[[1]]
```

allows to convert into a data frame.

Thanks to @Limey pointing me to check the output of

```
dput(acctInfo)
```

Showing nested structure of lists.